# Office 365 bulk deleting emails using Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I am in need of bulk deleting emails in one of our mailboxes that is full. I am wanting to bulk delete emails with a certain subject and also within a date range.

I know I can do something like this

```
Search-Mailbox -Identity "No Reply" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Mail delivery system"' -DeleteContent
```

I am however unsure how to add in the date range.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
search-mailbox -identity "No reply" -SearchQuery {received:mm/dd/yyyy..mm/dd/yyyy} -deletecontent
```

Comment: Thanks Wasif! That works for the date range however I also have to include the Subject into the search query for example 'Subject:"Mail delivery system"'